# Woocommerce show product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am a little confused as to that the issue is here, I am trying to pick out a specific product by doing this:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //I saw maximum execution time error on your image - this is for that
$args = array(
   'post_status'    => 'publish',
   'post_type'      => 'product',
   'meta_value'     => 'yes',
   'posts_per_page' => 10,
   'product_cat'    => 'grammar'
);
$product_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>


                    <?php while ( $product_query->have_posts() ) : $product_query->the_post(); global $product; ?>

                      <?php the_title(); ?>
                              <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post->post_excerpt ); ?>


                    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

But nothing is being produced. So I am creating a product under the relevant category and placing content into the description in both main and product short description but still nothing shows?

Comment: Please be more clear about what you want.  Are you _creating_ a product or trying to _show_ a product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably `'meta_value'  => 'yes',`. You need to specify a `meta_key` as well.

```
$args = array(
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'meta_key'       => 'my_meta_key',
    'meta_value'     => 'yes',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'product_cat'    => 'grammar'
);
```

I have no idea what the meta key should be so change `my_meta_key` into what you want. Also make sure that the the value for `product_cat` is correct. It should be the slug of the category.